# xcode, cannot see bar item in toolbar

Tags: xcode, xcode6

in xcode 6.2, I have a toolbar and 5 bar items. all bar items are not showing in the toolbar unless I click on it.  what do i fix it?

[image]

Comment: Do they have images set for unselected state?

Comment: @LordZsolt I do not have images set for bar items.